# Ionic slider with different image size or heights

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using `ion-slide-box`, but the issue is, my `ion-slides` image is not in the same size, its dynamically repeated different size image using ng-repeat

```
                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="sliderimages in sliderimages">
                        <img src={{sliderimages.url}} style="width:100%;height:auto;"/>
                    </ion-slide>
                </ion-slide-box>
```

I used this CSS to fit image height to all

```
.slider {
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
}
.slider-slide {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

but the height is not so fit[image: fit image]

[image: space in above]

I have to add any size of images and that to be fit in the Ionic slider.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also looking for this

Answer (score 3):

```
max-width: 100vw !important;
max-height: 100vh !important;
```

this worked for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do not apply an explicit width or height to the image tag. Instead, give it:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xwrvxser/1/

Regards.